# RegEx for validating an integer with a maximum length of 10 characters

Tags: regex

Could you please point me the appropriate RegEx for validating an integer with a maximum length of 10 characters?

Valid ones include: 1234567890

Comment: Would leading zeros be acceptable?

Comment: Yes leading zeros are acceptable

Comment: See my updates post with some kind useful information

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
[^0-9][+-]?[0-9]{1,10}[^0-9]
```

In words: Optional + or - followed by a digit, repeated one up to ten times. Note that most libraries have a shortcut for a digit: `\d`, hence the above could also be written as: `\d{1,10}`.

- http://rubular.com/r/kVygWuYMSN

Comment: Indeed seems that OP _wants_ leading zeros :)

Comment: Wouldn't this return a 15 digit number as well with first ten digits of that number?

Answer (score 37):

Don't forget that integers *can* be negative:

```
^\s*-?[0-9]{1,10}\s*$
```

Here's the meaning of each part:

- `^`: Match must start at beginning of string
- `\s`: Any whitespace character

  - `*`: Occurring zero or more times
- `-`: The hyphen-minus character, used to denote a negative integer

  - `?`: May or may not occur
- `[0-9]`: Any character whose ASCII code (or Unicode code point) is between '0' and '9'

  - `{1,10}`: Occurring at least one, but not more than ten times
- `\s`: Any whitespace character

  - `*`: Occurring zero or more times
- `$`: Match must end at end of string

This ignores leading and trailing whitespace and would be more complex if you consider commas acceptable or if you need to count the minus sign as one of the ten allowed characters.

Answer (score 5):

1 to 10:

```
[0-9]{1,10}
```

In [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966.aspx) (and not only, see the comment below) also valid (with a stipulation) this:

```
\d{1,10}
```

C#:

```
var regex = new Regex("^[0-9]{1,10}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
regex.IsMatch("1"); // true
regex.IsMatch("12"); // true
..
regex.IsMatch("1234567890"); // true
regex.IsMatch(""); // false
regex.IsMatch(" "); // true
regex.IsMatch("a"); // false
```

P.S. Here's a very [useful sandbox](http://www.rubular.com/r/DaIyrgKhJd).

Comment: Not only in .NET. But keep in mind that regex engines usually treat `\d` as *any decimal digit* which might include Arabic, Tamil, etc.

Comment: Not correct. `[0-9]{1,10}` will check the minimum length, instead of the maximum length (checking against `1234567890123123` will return true - https://rubular.com/r/hd2GAwIost977E
). Instead append the start and end-of-line chars as @guido suggested: `^[0-9]{1,10}$` - https://rubular.com/r/v7CbxE3m7ndEMj

Answer (score 4):

In most languages i am aware of, the actual regex for validating should be
`^[0-9]{1,10}$`; otherwise the matcher will also return positive matches if the to be validated number is part of a longer string.

Comment: @abatishchev: even after adding ^ and $, your regex is still wrong, because it matches " 123 34" which is NaN (as well as " "). The MYNN's is also wrong because it has no boundaries.

Comment: Yes, sure, you're right. Tomorrow night I read `leading zeros` like `whitespace` :-D anyway I don't know what for I was writing about spaces.. so I edited my post, Is it correct now?

Comment: sure; and the online sandbox to test regexes you suggested in your answer is a very good find

Answer (score 0):

**0123456789** is not a valid integer (usually zeros will be stripped)

I think something like this regexp would be better to use:

```
^[1-9]([0-9]*)$
```

(does not support signed numbers)

Comment: This question had a satisfactory answer over three and a half years ago. The OP specifically wants to allow leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
^\d{1,10}$
```

Check for examples:
[regex](https://regex101.com/r/kQf1cv/1)