# How to use jQuery input mask plugin with special character regex validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, input-mask

I want to utilize [inputmask plugin](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) for special character & maxlength validation for text box. It supports either one. Is there a way to implement this?

```
    var pattern = /^[\w\s\/\&\'\-]*$/i;
    $("#example1").inputmask("99-9999999");
    $("#example2").inputmask(pattern);
```

Comment: Is `example1` working correctly? And `example2`? What do you expect for a result? What is "this"?

Comment: Did you try as is written in the readme? *`<input id="example2" data-inputmask-regex="<<REGEX>>" />`* and then *`$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#example2").inputmask("Regex");
});`*?

Comment: No, its generic validation in my case for more than 100 fields having different input masks(allowed/non allowed characters) so I will prefer to do it via Javascript rather than HTML attributes

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702730/regex-for-validating-an-integer-with-a-maximum-length-of-10-characters) might help you.